# Parse.com sending push notification to multiple device types i.e Android and iOS not working

Tags: php, android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using following code to send parse.com push notification form my PHP form using REST API.

```
$APPLICATION_ID = 'Applicatio_id_here';
    $REST_API_KEY = 'Rest_api_key_here';


    $data = [
        'where' => ['channels' => ''],
        'expiry' => time() + 1000,
        'data' => [
            'alert' => $notification,
        ],
    ];
    $_data = json_encode($data);

    $headers = [
        'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
    ];

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($curl);
```

My parse.com account is setup for both Android and iOS push notification. And I am able to get notification on Android device successfully. But the problem is with the iPhone. I am not getting any notification on iPhone device.

But iPhone device is receiving notification successfully, if I send the notification from the parse.com admin (Send a push).

One more thing to mention, in parse.com admin, I could see Channel = ["global"] for iOS devices but [""] blank for Android device.
So I think there might be some problem in my PHP code.

If it is not possible to send same message with this code, please help me with some working code. I need this as my app for both devices are already online.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your "$data" to this one:

```
$data = [ 'where' => ['channels' => 'global'] OR  ['channels' => ''], 'expiry' => time()
```

Another option :

```
$data = ['where' => 'channels' => 'global' OR  'channels' => '', 'expiry' => time()
```

Comment: are you sure, this won't effect the android users, as for android it was [""] blank. I am using this same code to send notification for both IOS and Android device.

Comment: First try it, then we will see what you gonna do, I guess this will effect android users

Comment: yes, adding channels => global help, now iOS device received the notification. But i want it to be worked for android device too, without need to send notification two times, with, channels => global and channels => ""

Comment: Edited, look again and try both